# Using umbraco functions from another project

Tags: umbraco

I try to use in the umbraco functions to get data from DB. But not from the project that implement the umbraco, but from another project in a same solution.

Is there some nuget that can help me to add the the function of umbraco to the outer project? 
And what's the function of umbraco that get data from the database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll have to include [UmbracoCms.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms.Core/) with nuget

You can acces the database through [contentservice](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/contentservice) and [mediaservice](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/mediaservice)

There's an example available on github that accesses Umbraco through a console application that might be helpful: https://github.com/sitereactor/umbraco-console-example/

Comment: How is this not an answer if I may ask? This is literally what you need to do when you want to access umbraco data through a console app or another web app. Also the 2 provided links are to the official Umbraco documentation that has been around for several years now